# Trying to freeze the camera location in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, game-development

I'm trying to make the camera follow the player in unity 3D I attached the camera to the player but it also rotates with him cause he's a ball I don't want that to happen I added a rigidbody to the camera it worked one time IDK how but then it stopped following him due to the rigidbody any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have made your camera a child of your player? If so the camera will inherit all transformations on you player, which is definitely not what you want. You can follow this video to learn a camera follow script. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFQhpwc6cKE

And you will almost never need to put a rigidbody on a camera, so you can remove that.

Comment: Thx For your time I followed the tutorial and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Child objects always inherit the transform of the parent object, as Christopher already said. So, your camera will also spin around if the ball rolls through the world (controlled by the RigidBody / physics in this case).

In order to make the camera follow any object in the scene, you can use a separate GameObject for the camera, that follows the player object controlled by a simple script. - For example something like this (modified example from the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html)):

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class SmoothFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3f;
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0.0f, 5.0f, -10.0f);
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    void Update()
    {
        // Define a target position above and behind the target transform
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.TransformPoint(offset);

        // Smoothly move the camera towards that target position
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
            targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
        
        // Make the camera point towards the target
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of script component in Unity Inspector window]

(*This is a very basic question, and has been answered many times before. You can easily find many similar examples by just searching the web. - And the title of the post doesn't really match the question. It's important to find the right words and cues in order to keep this site working nicely (clear technical questions -> clear answers).*)

Comment: I tried it but it seems not working for me the camera just keeps going up and down DK why .

Comment: Hi! I've modified the script above and added the LookAt() call, maybe that's going to fix the problem? If the player object moves, the camera should always place itself behind the target/player, the offset is now adjustable in the inspector (y -> world units above the player, z -> units behind the player). - You can observe the camera object in the Scene view, while in Play Mode, and also keep adjusting the settings if needed... I hope this helps getting started with your project!